# How to get ObjectID from Spring (via MongoDB) in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring, mongodb, objectid

I get data from MongoDB and want to console.log the ID from that Data.

Here is a code example:

```
//The Person class
import { ObjectId } from "bson";

export class Person{
    personID: ObjectId;
    constructor(personID: ObjectId){
        this.personID = personID;
    }
    getPersonID(){
      return this.personID;
    }
}

//In app.component.ts:
ngOnInit(): void{
this.personService.findAll().subscribe(
    (response: Person[]) => {
      this.persones= response.map((person) => 
        new Person(
          person.personID
        ));
      console.log(response);
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      alert(error.message);
    }
    );
}

public valueOfBtn(event: MouseEvent) {
      for(var person of this.persones){
        person.getPersonID();
      }
  }
```

What i am getting is the following:
Object { timestamp: 1679471923, date: "2023-03-22T07:58:43.000+00:00" }
as output.

When i do something like this:

```
getPersonID(){
      return this.personID.id;
}
```

the output is undefined.

The Person has a objectID and i can get that ID via Spring and output those.

It would be great to know, how i can get that ID in Angular.

Thank you very much!

I tried diffrent formatting. But nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

With the info you provide, the angular code is doing what you expected. So the parameter `personID` is getting ignored before instantiating Person class. Maybe on personService.findAll(), or even in the backend, check your backend log, and browser network

Comment: What do you mean by getting ignored? I don't want to ingore the personID.

Comment: normally people put snippets, and payload message from the API, if you could provide more info in your question would be great.

Comment: I do have another problem, where i can't check if personID is instanceof ObjectId.. I get errors. 
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

Comment: "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experiments": {
      "topLevelAwait": true
    },
  }

Comment: I realy dont know, whats going on.

Comment: Remember that ObjectID is a string. In JavaScript ObjectID is much more a pattern than a type. Of course you can do instanceof ObjectId, only if you rewrape the _id from JSON.

Comment: I really dont have enough info to help you. 
Can you make an Postman request to your API, and post here the print?

Comment: Why is ObjectId a string? In the documentation of bson.d.ts over the class ObjectId its a representation of a BSON type. As soon as i implement a method from the ObjectId class it cannot find that method. If you say, that ObjectId is a string in Javascript its clear, that i cannot take control over that methods. As soon as i write new ObjectId i get the error shown above. Im sorry but its senesetive data and i cannot print that here. I realy hope that you can help by that example. When you need more like a service class etc. i can post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252718/discussion-between-riheldo-melo-and-benedikt-muller).

Comment: Okei im in the room